# Merging Two rows using Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I have a table containing data.
I want to introduce a feature that if I drag a row of the table onto another row, the contents of the two rows get merged in the database as well as in the table.
The table is :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="editable-sample">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Activitys[0].Activity_Text)</th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Activitys[0].Deliverable)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Activitys[0].Project.Name)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Activitys[0].ActivityType.Activity_Type)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Activitys[0].Activity_Date)
                                    </th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @{List<int> MergedActivity = ViewBag.IsMerged;}
                               @foreach (var item in Model.Activitys)
                               {
                                   DateTime sDate = item.Activity_Date;
                                   string  date = sDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

                                    <tr class="">
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedGroups" value="@item.ID" id="@item.ID" class="chk" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <b><u>
                                                    @Html.ActionLink(StringTruncate.TruncateString(item.Activity_Text, 15, TruncateOptions.IncludeEllipsis), "Edit", "Activities", new { id = item.ID }, null)
                                                </u></b>
                                                    @if (item.IsImported)
                                                    {
                                                        <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>

                                                    }
                                                    @if (MergedActivity.Contains(item.ID))
                                                    {
                                                        <i class="fa fa-random"></i>

                                                    }

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @StringTruncate.TruncateString(item.Deliverable,15, TruncateOptions.IncludeEllipsis)
                                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Deliverable)*@
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @StringTruncate.TruncateString(item.Project.Name,15, TruncateOptions.IncludeEllipsis)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @StringTruncate.TruncateString(item.ActivityType.Activity_Type, 9, TruncateOptions.IncludeEllipsis)
                                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActivityType.Activity_Type)*@
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @date
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

I need a jquery to implement merging of two rows using drag and drop.
Thanks

Comment: Look https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable, this may help you

Comment: you have to learn how to use these plugins https://jqueryui.com/droppable/  and https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I studied them but not able to do achieve my goal .A little more help would be nice.

Comment: @smriti, for example if you have 2 different Project.Name then how will you merge the row rows?

Comment: For project name It will save the project name of the row which is being dragged and drop  the project name of the other row